# Azure app service running .net and node/express app

Tags: azure, nginx, web-applications, reverse-proxy, azure-web-app-service

Is it possible to run .net application (FooApp) and a node/express.js application (BarApp) in Azure and have it configured under the same host name like contoso.com/foo  &  contoso.com/bar . Is this possible wthout using a reverse proxy? preferably under the same app service plan?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please have a try to config a Virtual directory (For example:site/foo) on the Azure portal as following screenshot:

[image]

When we push the application to the Azure web app, we need to include the virtual directory path in the Site Name and Destination URL sections on the Connection tab as below:

[image]

After publishing successfully, we can visit it via: `http://yourcustomdomain/foo`